# produce a matrix in a more efficient way

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am looking for a more efficient way to make the following matrix `L`:

```
      |2 -2  0 0 0     |
      |-1 2 -1 0 0  0  |
      |0 -1 2 -1 0     |
(1/2).|0 0 -1 2 -1     |
      |      . . .     |   
      |  0    0 -1 2 -1|
      |       0  0 -2 2|
```

So far I have got this:

```
L = diag(ones(n,1)*2)- ...
    diag(ones(n-1,1),1) - ... 
    diag(ones(n-1,1),-1);
L(1,2) = -2; 
L(end,end-1) = -2;
L = L/2;
```

for instance for `n=5` it produces:

```
L =

    1.0000   -1.0000         0         0         0
   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000         0         0
         0   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000         0
         0         0   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000
         0         0         0   -1.0000    1.0000
```

`n` can be a value in range `[5 1000]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead, try using 2D convolution with [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) where the input is the identity matrix and a horizontal `[-0.5 1 -0.5]` filter tap is the kernel.  This is nice because you can consider this identity matrix as an image and you are performing an [edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) where the only time you will get a coefficient of 1 in the output is when the centre of the kernel is directly on top of a 1.  If the kernel centre is not on a 1 but any of the elements are touching a 1, the result would be -0.5.  This is nice but it doesn't handle the border cases with the top and bottom row.  That unfortunately you have to modify manually.  We can escape using two statements to modify the elements in favour of using column-major indexing instead.  This solution certainly beats using 3 `diag` calls IMHO.

```
n = 5;
L = conv2(eye(n), [-0.5 1 -0.5], 'same');
L([n+1 end-n]) = -1;
```

Result:

```
>> L

L =

    1.0000   -1.0000         0         0         0
   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000         0         0
         0   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000         0
         0         0   -0.5000    1.0000   -0.5000
         0         0         0   -1.0000    1.0000
```

Comment: Cool answer, Tnx.

Comment: @CKT You would have to construct the Toeplitz matrix first before performing the multiplication with the kernel to do the convolution and I would argue that doing that is less syntax friendly than using `conv2` which is one line.  I believe NKN is looking for elegant solutions... not necessarily faster ones.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
n = 5;
L = full(spdiags(repmat([-1 2 -1],n,1), [-1 0 1], zeros(n)));
L([n+1 end-n]) = -2;
```

Comment: This was my original answer +1, but I decided to change it because I didn't like so many nested calls: `full`, `spdiags`, `repmat` etc. :)

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I would have chosen convolution first :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! Quite fascinating +1